# CTRL + dragging into a newly created UIViewController file

Tags: swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

I created a new file called GamePlayController.swift and made it a class of type UIViewController. I intend to make it like the GameViewController.swift that is created by default, but I am wondering why it is not letting me CTRL + drag Tap Gestures from Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your viewController is an outlet, you can't connect CTRL+Drag. You need to set the class in your nib, of the view controller class.

[image]